# Zend Form Object as a string

Tags: database, string, forms, zend-framework

I have a system which has certain page content stored in the database. Within this text we have the ability to add in custom scripts such as {WIDGET_FORM} which replaces the text with the content of a class named app_resource_widget_form.  Up until now this has worked but the form needs to be created by Zend Form. Unfortunately the function which creates this requires a string(html) to be returned as so far i can only return the zend form object.  Does any one know if what i am trying to do is possible.  At some point the form must get created as html, is there a way to manually call this and then use that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Zend_Form` has a `__toString()` method, so:

```
$html = str_replace('{WIDGET_FORM}', $form->__toString(), $html);
```